# What decides the table name in many to many relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many

For the example, lets say I have a rails application with questions and tags. Each question can have multiple tags, and each tag can have multiple questions.

In my question model I would have `has_and_belongs_to_many :tags` and vice-versa.

What will the default many-to-many table be? Will it be `tags_questions`, or `questions_tags`.

The reason I ask, is because I have a many to many, and sometimes it is looking for `tags_questions`, and other queries look for `questions_tags`.

Comment: Can you give us an example, when it's looking for `tags_questions` instead of `questions_tags`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some information about this in the API documentation.

> [..]So a join between Developer and Project will give the default join table name of “developers_projects” because ***“D” precedes “P” alphabetically***. Note that this precedence is calculated using the < operator for String. This means that if the strings are of different lengths, and the strings are equal when compared up to the shortest length, then the longer string is considered of higher lexical precedence than the shorter one. For example, one would expect the tables “paper_boxes” and “papers” to generate a join table name of “papers_paper_boxes” because of the length of the name “paper_boxes”, but it in fact generates a join table name of “paper_boxes_papers”. Be aware of this caveat, and use the custom :join_table option if you need to. If your tables share a common prefix, it will only appear once at the beginning. For example, the tables “catalog_categories” and “catalog_products” generate a join table name of “catalog_categories_products”. - [API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many)

So basically it should be ordered alphabetically, except in the case it's getting too long or the tables sharing a common prefix. You could define your join table via the `:join_table` parameter-

Answer (score 0):

It's always alphabetical order, so it should be `questions_tags`.